# Multiple Write statements to get output in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple for and write statements in my code , i an looking to get the output of each write statement in different rows in the csv file

```
with open("csvtest_new.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for namespace in namespaces:
        writer.writerow(namespace['name'])
        x = client.bucket.list(namespace['name'])
        bucketlist = x['object_bucket']
        for bucket in bucketlist:
            writer.writerow(bucket['name'])
```

Result : All in one row

```
ae
"2b30c894e9bf42bc9033c7"
"fdb7911f39014ea682c7329"
aeims
"b5b54ae564ba"
"b788837b21ed4"
```

Expected

```
Row 1        Row 2
ae           "2b30c894e9bf42bc9033c7"
             "fdb7911f39014ea682c7329"
aeims        "b5b54ae564ba"
             "b788837b21ed4"
```

Comment: They're not rows, they're _columns_ and I half suspect that that confusion is causing you the issue when using `writerow`. You need empty strings, `''`, to fill the columns on each row

Answer (score -1):

I would think of trying to break it up into "cells". Remember a csv has a comma after each input and then you can get to the next row by the \n i believe it is. So, create a function to make each individual cell and call that inside your loops. Key tip, try to only open and close the csv as least often as possible, can run into errors with windows not being able to keep up.